# The charger`s output current

Tags: electricity, electric-circuits, electric-current

How can a mobile charger's output current be 1 or 2 Ampere if 1 Ampere is a deadly value for a human, but when I touch the output wire I don't feel anything?

Comment: I edited the post for grammar and spelling without changing the content.  However, you should note that the current is equal to the voltage *divided by* the resistance.  You also appear to be asking a separate question about how a charger works in the second paragraph - if this is not your intent, you should either edit the question or remove that paragraph entirely.

Comment: For a given resistance, a higher voltage produces a higher current (up until something pops).  The output voltage is far more critical in determining if the device can be lethal.

Comment: @J.Murray, oh I was inattantive

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The charger can supply a maximum of 1 or 2 Amps to a low resistance circuit in your phone. That doesn't mean 1amp flows through you when you touch it - you are a much higher resistance.

Whether 1 amp would harm you is also a bit more complicated. 1 Amp of low voltage DC would flow harmlessly over the outside of your skin, you wouldn't even feel the heating effect. At higher voltages 1amp could flow into your muscles causing them to contract, while 1000Amps of high voltage DC from say a subway train would heat you a little less harmlessly

The real danger comes from higher voltage AC, this can travel through your body and interfere with the electrical signals in your heart. As little as 20-30mA can be fatal if it flows across your chest

Comment: 1 amp of low voltage DC *wouldn't flow through you, period*. It's like saying that if you fell very fast from a low height (on Earth) you'd be okay. Well, you **can't** actually fall very fast from a low height.